# Why does innerHTML does not work after servlet is posting a response?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, httpresponse

I want the response from the servlet to be captured in the jsp page. I use javascript for this. Here is the code:

TestServlet.java:

```
    package com.test;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        String testString = "Load Check";
        //request.setAttribute("test", testString);
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("").include(request, response);
        response.getWriter().write("Test Success");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Test.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function callServeltAndGetResponse(){
    var servlet = new XMLHttpRequest();
    servlet.onreadystatechange = function(){
        var servletResponse = servlet.responseText;
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = servletResponse;
    }
    servlet.open('GET','TestServlet',true);
}

    </script>
    <form onSubmit="javascript:callServletAndGetResponse()">
    <input type=submit>
    </form>
    <div id="response"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the above jsp page, the divcontent is not changed by the javascript though servlet writes a response. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have missed this `servlet.send();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default form submit process or the page will reload

Try:

```
<form onSubmit="javascript:callServletAndGetResponse(); return false">
```

Comment: that didnot still load the response on jsp

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to check for status (200) and expected response